# De Almeida-Thouless line and spin glass in the Hopfield network

Tags: statistical-mechanics, symmetry-breaking, spin-models, ferromagnetism, disorder

From the SK model, the Almeida-Thouless line appears to divide the stable paramagnetic phase and unstable spin-glass phase in the presence of an external magnetic field.

However, in the case of a Hopfield network, the AT line appears in the stable spin-glass+ferromagnetic phase which divides the RS solution and Parisi RSB solution.

I am trying to understand the idea behind the AT line, but I cannot grab the common general feature of those models. The only thing I can see is that both stable paramagnetic phase and the RS solution of stable spin-glass phase are ergodic. As I have understood, the RSB solution of spin glass is non-ergodic since there are infinitely many distinct overlaps(?), but I am not sure about the unstable spin-glass phase from the SK model.

※ I am new to a disorder physics and replica method. If there are mistakes in technical terms and concepts, please be generous : )